# Email alter to everyday using Time-Dependent Workflow Action in salesforce

Tags: email-alert, time-dependent-workflow

I want implement Time-Dependent WF Action for 15 days before the due date. Will it send email-alter to every day before the due date(I mean all 15 days)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, it won't send recursive emails.

Comment: it works through configuration itself, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using simple Workflow. You can vote this idea.

[Recurring Time-Based Workflow Actions/Email Alerts](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kymqAAA)

This types of requirement can be easily handled by Batch apex. Just schedule a batch daily who will pick all the matching records and will send email on them.

Trailhead module for you. [Use Batch Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/asynchronous_apex/units/async_apex_batch)

Answer (score 1):

To create a recursive action you need to do some trick.

Create a datetime (lets say `schedule_datetime__c` field) field based on which you want to perform time based action to send an email.

Define workflow flow rule based on which it will satisfy the criteria like `schedule_datetime__c < Due_Date__c`

In the time based workflow, perform 2 action.

1. Send a email 1 hour before `schedule_datetime__c`.
2. Create a field update which will update `schedule_datetime__c + 1 day`. In the field update configuration, be sure to select `Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change` which will help to fire workflow again.

This way, everytime after firing the action, `schedule_datetime__c` will be updated to next day and workflow will pull the action.

This solution also works for a scenario like if you want to send birthday wish every year to your customer.